# Need to get constant value for SQL IN where value do not returns

Tags: mysql, sql

While trying to get data from a table using IN operator in SQL Query, if there is no row available for that criteria, no row will be return, as per below example :

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM employee_tbl;
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-04-06 |                100 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-06-06 |                300 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                350 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

mysql> SELECT daily_typing_pages FROM employee_tbl WHERE name IN ( 'John','Ram' ,'XYZ');

O/p will be as below with only 2 row :

```
daily_typing_pages  |
--------------------+
                250 |
                220 |
```

What I need is to have some constant value in case where the value do not match. So the output I am expecting is

```
daily_typing_pages  |
--------------------+
                250 |
                220 |
                100 |
```

Is is possible to achieve this ?

Edit: Finally going with setting the values of of SQL.

Comment: +1 A tricky one, but not **impossible!**

Comment: do you have a table where all users (also "XY") are contained? Then you could use a left/right join and ifnull. Otherwhise it gets tricky.

Comment: the example is a bit confusing. Do you want to get max daily, daily per date, and more importantly do you want entries with jack to return constantvalue ( eg 100) or anything that is not one if the names in the IN set.

Comment: @meewok Need constant value (eg 100) or anything when the criteria mentioned in IN operator do not have in the give table. Please you can use any other example of your own if you like

Comment: Updated my post. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have several options to achieve this. However, most of them are workarounds to "bypass" a problem. The Problem is simple that your data is inconsistent. Selecting a user that does not exist shoudln't result in anything (which happens but is NOT your desired outcome).

Option 1.) Fix the data: Insert the missing User XY into the table, leave unset values to NULL. (then you can use `IFNULL(pages, 100)` or whatever default value you like

Option 2.) Str2Rows: You could create a stored procedure or function, that allows you to dynamically convert a string given like `A,B,C` into a temporary table of three rows, so you could to your lef/right join with the employee_tbl.

Option 3.) Result Table: Create a table, equal to your user table. Insert just the names you want to query AND the default value. Then Do a `SELECT INTO` from your employee table. (Default values for XY will remain untouched)

Option 4.) Insert values for non existing users OUT OF SQL (so when displaying the result)

However "better" than removing symptoms is to **fix** the reason, so i suggest you to go with Option 1.

---

Edit: Option 3 could look like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82f9e/2

1.) Clear your result table (note that name needs to be unique for Replace to work)

2.) Insert your required results into your resultTable:

```
INSERT InTO employee_result (name,pages) VALUES ("John", NULL);
INSERT InTO employee_result (name,pages) VALUES ("Ram", NULL);
INSERT InTO employee_result (name,pages) VALUES ("XY", NULL);
```

3.) Replace the null values for those users that have values:

```
REPLACE INTO employee_result (name, pages) SELECT name, pages FROM employee_tbl
WHERE name in (SELECT name FROM employee_result);
```

4.) Retrieve the resultset and set a default value for those who have no own value.

```
SELECT name, IFNULL(pages,100) from employee_result;
```

This can be "modified" to work with stored procedures and temporary tables, too. (that would be Option 2)

Hope it helps.

Comment: What I have given here is just an example, in real application, the primary key is been added and deleted based on some conditions. Hence it is not possible to achieve any of your workaround

Comment: Thank you @dognose for your effort. But I am afraid that creating new table is not possible. We need to execute this query in every min or less. If we can not be able to do it from SQL Query, than have to go with your option 4 as final solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and example a UNION between two queries may be quite simple to solve your problem:

**Union**

```
(SELECT daily_typing_pages FROM employee_tbl WHERE name IN ( 'John','Ram' ,'XYZ'))
UNION
(SELECT constantValue FROM employee_tbl WHERE NOT name IN ( 'John','Ram' ,'XYZ'))
```

See: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: Thats not working. If emloyee_tbl does not contain "XYZ", this row will not be included. you now will receive `constantValue` without knowing to which user it belongs. And something like `contantValue, name` cannot be done.

Comment: Also having 2 users with an equal value, will just show one of them. So having 4 users not in the table will return only "one times" constantvalue

Comment: @meewok, thank you for your answer, however the NOT IN result in the rows which are not needed from the tables.

Comment: @dognose, you can consider user as primary , so no two user can be same.

Comment: @Ayush considered that, but talking about the 'daily_typing_pages' value. If you only select that value, no duplicates are possible. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85027/1 (okay, could be fixed with UNION ALL, but still: The NOT IN Part is wrong. It results in listing all users from the table NOT IN the given array - not the other way round :)

Comment: @ayush I'm confused , you want to replace daily for users not inthose three but you don't want the rows that don't have those three ....

Comment: you use the second query to get a resultset where daily is constant value eg 100. you unite that with the resultset of records containing the names you want.

Comment: @meewok: Imagine the table contains 'John, Ram, Zara, Peter' and the Query is done for 'John, Ram, XY' - Then the TC wants to have the values for John and Ram and Default for XY. Your Query would return values for John and Ram and Default for Zara and Peter.

Comment: this is true about what he wants?

Comment: @meewoK To make is simple, I want the value which is there in Table for the criteria mentioned in IN operator, and criteria which are not in Table, any constant/default value

Answer (score 0):

You can `SELECT name, (CASE WHEN name IN('John','Ram' ,'XYZ') THEN daily_typing_pages ELSE 100 END) FROM employee_tbl`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, but the result give the rows which are not asked for in IN Operator. I have tried the above in postgres

Comment: Sorry, I got confused about what you expect, now I see what you mean.